# What do we actually mean when we say "light"?

Tags: optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, terminology

light is an electromagnetic wave , but can we say all EM  wave are light?
eg. infrared radiation , uv radiation ... can we say these as light?

Comment: Light is those EM waves (frequencies) to which the eye is sensitive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the time, light means electromagnetic waves in the visible part of the spectrum.

But sometimes people talk about all electromagnetic waves as light.

If there is doubt, visible light is a clearer term to use.